# How to exit a .JS process so it returns a StdOut value to AHK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, autohotkey

I have a NodeJS script that is launched by an AutoHotKey script. I need this NodeJS script to return a specific value when exiting, so [it can be retrieved and used by the AHK script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm). I am able to get the value returned by the process directly in my AHK script, but it's not the wanted one.

How do I make my process return a specific value?

So far, I tried using

`process.exit(myValue);` and

`process.exitCode = myValue;` and

`process.stdout.write(myValue)` but none of this works.

Here is my AHK script (which works fine) :

```
RunWait, C:\path_to_node\node.exe C:\path_to_script\index.js,,, output
MsgBox, %output%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output is only the Process ID (PID).  You need to run your .js in a WSH wrapper, and your .js needs to return StdOut as follows:

Here is the AHK "secret sauce" RunWaitStdOut:

```
MsgBox % RunWaitStdOut("C:\path_to_script\index.js")

RunWaitStdOut(command)
{
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /c node " command)
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll() 
}
```

And in the meantime, the end of your .js should have something like the following generating the StdOut:

```
    process.stdout.write("The Result this javascript returns to AHK is " + myValue);
```

And remember, StdOut is a string, so if your `myValue` is a number or such, you may need the `toString()` method (as OP noticed, per OP's comment):

```
    process.stdout.write( myValue.toString() );
```

Hth,

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I had some trouble making it working as I tried to return a number instead of a string in the `process.stdout.write()`. Now it's working great !

Comment: Cool.  What did you do?  Was it just `myValue.toString()` that you changed?

Comment: Yes, I needed to return a generated number (e.g 5634), and decided to remove the `.toString()`, so I just added it back

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm):

> RunWait sets `ErrorLevel` to the program's exit code (a signed 32-bit integer). If UseErrorLevel is in effect and the launch failed, the word `ERROR` is stored.

So you can get the exit code via `ErrorLevel`:

```
RunWait, C:\path_to_node\node.exe C:\path_to_script\index.js
output := ErrorLevel
MsgBox, %output%
```

Note that the exit code is a 32-bit signed integer and is set to 1 if `node` encounters an error. If you need proper output, use stdout, as [suggested by PGilm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582826/9253414).