# AutoHotKey - defining a variable from the output of a program ran inside AHK

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script that automatically toggles between 100% and 150% scale on Windows and I found
https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI
which is perfect for this specifically as it just outputs the needed value, but I don't know how to run the program inside the script, then define a variable with said output.
BTW, it's probably relevant to mention this is AHKv2

The script would be something like:

```
Run "SetDPI.exe value 1"
currentscale:= OUTPUT GOES HERE
if(currentscale == 100)
    {
        Run "SetDpi.exe 150 1"
    }
    else
    {
        Run "SetDpi.exe 100 1"
    }
```

I know this is unoptimized but it'd do.

Comment: See [Example #7](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Run.htm#ExStdOut) for the `Run` command to learn how to capture output from StdOut.

Comment: Here is a good working reference implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580802/how-to-exit-a-js-process-so-it-returns-a-stdout-value-to-ahk/62582826#62582826